# php img src not working in my code

Tags: php

I just want to show my image in my table, but it's not working.
This my code. Can anyone help me?

```
<td class="sn">
<?php
   $gambar = explode(",", $m['path']);
   $id = $m['check_id'];
   $type = $m['type'];
       if($gambar == ''){
          echo"No Image !";
       }else{
         foreach ($gambar as $value) {
            $url = "/public/photo/chec/".$id."/".$type."/".$value;
        ?>
           <img src="<?php echo $url;?>" />
        <?php
        }       
       }
        ?>
</td>
```

Comment: what is `$m`, what does it contain? I suppose it is the result of a call to `preg_match`, but exactly what does it contain?

Comment: Have a look, in the browser, at the source of the HTML page, this will probably tell you more. Is there an <img> tag? Is is correct? if not then do one of the variables have a different content than you expect? Instead of `?><img src="<?php echo $url;?>" /><?php` I would write the much simpler: `echo '<img src="'.$url.'">';`

Comment: Inspect Element your img src in your browser to see what url rendered  sure you will find what's wrong with the code